# Fastest way to merge two dictionaries

Tags: python

In looking at the methods for merging a dictionary in python, I have found two different methods that appear to have the same functionality.

`{**dict1, **dict2}`

and

`dict1 | dict2`

Aside from the latter only being available in 3.9 and above, it seems as though these two methods have the same functionality. That is, they both take in two dictionaries like the following:

```
dict1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
dict2 = {'c': 3, 'd': 4}
```

and return `{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}`

My question is, is one of these methods dramatically (or even slightly) quicker than the other? Are there any other differences in these two methods?

**EDIT**
Thanks for all the replies. In general, it seems as though the two methods listed above aren't significantly different in speed.

One note that was pointed out in the comments is that the `ChainMap()` function in the `collections` library does show some improvements when dealing with dictionaries of sufficient scale:

```
python3 -m timeit -n 1000 "x={'x_'+str(i):True for i in range(10000)};y={'y_'+str(i):True for i in range(10000)};x|y"

1000 loops, best of 5: 7.22 msec per loop
```

```
python3 -m timeit -n 1000 "from collections import ChainMap;x={'x_'+str(i):True for i in range(10000)};y={'y_'+str(i):True for i in range(10000)};ChainMap(x,y)"

1000 loops, best of 5: 4.16 msec per loop
```

Comment: why dont you check which one is fasted one ?

Comment: There is also `dict1.update(dict2)` if you don't mind mutating `dict1`.

Comment: Let's say they have intersecting keys? How do you want to handle merging them? Replace the values in dict1 with the values in dict2? Put both values into a list/tuple?

Comment: Some one has timed this [#Day27 – Fastest Way to Combine Dictionaries](https://www.realpythonproject.com/day27-fastest-way-to-combine-dictionaries/) using six different methods.  That said, just write what's clearest.  If you have a speed issue, profile your code and optimize the slow parts. Premature optimization leads to less clear, less maintainable code.

Comment: There are no differences that I'm aware of, and neither is significantly faster. I'm a little confused why a dict union operator was put into the language in the first place, this just seems to add another way to do the same thing.   ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @wim The rationale is spelled out in [PEP 584 – Add Union Operators To dict](https://peps.python.org/pep-0584/#motivation)

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Yes, I'm aware, but I find the PEP unconvincing. For example it says _`{**d1, **d2}` ignores the types of the mappings and always returns a dict_ - well, so does the union operator. It calls the unpacking "ugly" but that seems opinion-based, I find it more clear and obvious personally. Regarding `|=`, it says _`e.update(d2)` is not an expression and needs a temporary variable_ - well, so what?

Answer (score -1):

The key difference is that `**` supports any mapping, while `|` requires both operands to be dicts:

```
class C:
    def keys(self):
        return 'xyz'
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return item + '!'

a = {'foo': 'bar'}
c = C()

print( {**a, **c} ) # ok
print( a | c )      # nope
```

Note that unlike `|`, `|=` does work for mappings, so `a |= c` would be fine. This is similar to `list+list` vs `list += iterable`.

Comment: `|` doesn't require that.  But you're obliged to implement `C.__ror__` for defining what you want to happen here, explicitly.

Comment: And a related difference is that `{**a, **b}` requires the *result* to be a dict, whereas `a | b` is an `OrderedDict` for `OrderedDict` `a`, for example.

Comment: @wim: in that sense, you can say every operator is supported for everything.... if you implement it. The _built-in_ `|` only supports `dict|dict`.

Comment: @Ry: this is because you can't redefine literals. `{ whatever }` is always a dict (well, when it's not a set ;)

Comment: @gog `|` is not a built-in and doesn't "support" anything.  It's the `dict` type which supports operator `|`, by implementing datamodel hook `__or__`.  I still think this claim in answer _"`|` requires both operands to be dicts"_ is wrong or at best poorly worded.

Comment: @gog: I literally just gave an example where a built-in mapping type other than dict supports `|`.

Comment: @Ry: `OrderedDict` _is_ `dict` and not just some mapping. The point being, the `|` implementation is nominal, not structural. Check out https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/dictobject.c#L3570